# (NodeJS) event listener between two programs

Tags: node.js, event-listener

I'm making a multiplayer game, and i want the board to display whenever the player calls a function in his respective .js file, is there a way to use an event listener between two different js components?
Btw, i have a mediator server used for storing the game state, maybe that could help.

Comment: https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v16.x/docs/api/events.html or https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-ipc for multiple processes

Comment: you can use Event Emitter